JQ does not process part of the data
I can simplify the question by providing a link to the source data:
curl -sX GET "https://platform-explorer.pshenmic.dev/dataContract/GWRSAVFMjXx8HpQFaNJMqBV7MBgMK4br5UESsB4S31Ec/documents?page=23&limit=4" | jq -r .resultSet

At the end of the code, you can change the value of "limit", which will determine how many blocks are output. There are more than 1,000 blocks in total, and I need to extract the "label" and "timestamp" information for each block.
`
Inside  there are identical blocks that contain the raw data for the "data" key.
{
  "identifier": "BVC9GYvsAwswBTfv4C2eziRZmZ6fUzrmMuvqv1VPdWG3",
  "dataContractIdentifier": "GWRSAVFMjXx8HpQFaNJMqBV7MBgMK4br5UESsB4S31Ec",
  "revision": 1,
  "txHash": "03CFE8DAB06ECCCDB1430F149041775263F85DF335046C0421449AA73A46B4DA",
  "deleted": false,
  "data": "{\"label\":\"BFWookie\",\"records\":{\"identity\":\"Ea8acQwhQbbdaTLytoTiedEkTA89A8dyFpn9jTivr4Ht\"},\"preorderSalt\":\"hwebwVCxW+MwBmIqhoYIibGd7s7GOihv+MU6ae8Jj70=\",\"subdomainRules\":{\"allowSubdomains\":false},\"normalizedLabel\":\"bfw00k1e\",\"parentDomainName\":\"dash\",\"normalizedParentDomainName\":\"dash\"}",
  "timestamp": "2024-10-23T05:40:07.923Z",
  "isSystem": false,
  "owner": "Ea8acQwhQbbdaTLytoTiedEkTA89A8dyFpn9jTivr4Ht"
}

I need to convert the data from the "data" key into the correct format :

{
"label": "BFWookie",
"records": {
"identity": "Ea8acQwhQbbdaTLytoTiedEkTA89A8dyFpn9jTivr4Ht"
},
"preorderSalt": "hwebwVCxW+MwBmIqhoYIibGd7s7GOihv+MU6ae8Jj70=",
"subdomainRules": {
"allowSubdomains": false
},
"normalizedLabel": "bfw00k1e",
"parentDomainName": "dash",
"normalizedParentDomainName": "dash"
}

I obtained the last one by processing the data from the "data" key using the following command :
echo  "{\"label\":\"BFWookie\",\"records\":{\"identity\":\"Ea8acQwhQbbdaTLytoTiedEkTA89A8dyFpn9jTivr4Ht\"},\"preorderSalt\":\"hwebwVCxW+MwBmIqhoYIibGd7s7GOihv+MU6ae8Jj70=\",\"subdomainRules\":{\"allowSubdomains\":false},\"normalizedLabel\":\"bfw00k1e\",\"parentDomainName\":\"dash\",\"normalizedParentDomainName\":\"dash\"}" | jq

But how can this be done quickly during the first data processing stage?
Or another option?

From the corresponding Staging Ground post in response to how to parse a JSON String with jq (or other alternatives)?: "the code "jq'.data| from json | .label" works, but it does not solve my question, I need to get both "label" and "tamestump" at the same time. And the sed command is possible to solve the problem, but it is slow for 1000 blocks."

What's the "real" expected output from the extraction?

Recursively convert all json strings not just .data
jq 'walk(fromjson? // .)'


Thanks! I was looking for it too and didn't find it! This is what I originally wanted, but I couldn't do it!  Thanks!

I use your method and everything works, but when I decided to sort the entire array by the "timestamp" key, the sorting does not work.
sort_by(.timestamp)
It works if you put commas between the blocks and put the entire array in square brackets.
[ { ... }, { ... } ]
The command you provided works, but removes the commas.
How do I save the commas or rearrange them between the blocks?

@MikhailAmk -
jq '.resultSet|walk(fromjson? // .)|sort_by(.timestamp)'

You didn't provide the expected output but from what I understand you want to do something like this:
curl -sX GET "https://..." |
jq '.resultSet[] |
    {
      "label": (.data | fromjson | .label),
      "timestamp": .timestamp
    }
'

{
  "label": "BFWookie",
  "timestamp": "2024-10-23T05:40:07.923Z"
}
...


You got it right and this is what I need! The first is the best solution! Thanks!

If you like this answer mark it as accepted to let other users know your problem is  solved.

You can directly extract, decode, and format the required fields from the data key while retrieving the data. This minimizes post-processing.
curl -sX GET "https://platform-explorer.pshenmic.dev/dataContract/GWRSAVFMjXx8HpQFaNJMqBV7MBgMK4br5UESsB4S31Ec/documents?page=23&limit=4" | \
jq -r '.resultSet[] | .data | fromjson | .'


I'm losing the "timestamp" key
